# How can I validate Items or Maps in a List when using Firebase's Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I cannot find a solution for validating the **contents** of Lists in firestore. Is there any solution for doing this?

I don't want to use a new collection as it doesn't make sense for such a small amount of data (and will end up costing many more reads than necessary, and is much more convenient to keep the data under the original document).

Storing a few image details per document:

```
[
  {
    "filename": "example.png",
    "author": "example",
    "caption": "...",
  },
  ...
]
```

or, storing a few tags per document:

```
[
  "tag text 1",
  "tag text 2",
  ...
]
```

How can I access each item (or loop through?) to validate them, so that in the first example with the images, it can be validated so (for example):

- each item is a map,
- filename is a string,
- author is a string,
- caption is a string of a particular length

Or, for the tags example,

- each item is a string of a particular length?

Or is there a better solution to storing this sort of data in a document without creating a new collection or subcollection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I access each item (or loop through?) to validate them.

If you're asking about doing this in server-side security rules, then you've precisely hit the nail on the head: there is no ability to loop in Firebase's server-side security rules. See the [reference documentation for the operations that *can* be performed on a `List` in a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List). This limits what can be accomplished in security rules, and as far as I can see none of the use-cases you mention can be implemented with just security rules.

The simplest approach I can think of is by using Cloud Functions to implement the logic. You could *either* have the Cloud Function inspect the documents in place in the current collection, *or* you can have the client write to a different collection (of "pending" documents), have the Cloud Function validate the document, and move it to the actual collection.

Comment: Thanks Frank! I thought that might be the case but wanted to check. A cloud functions solution it is.